# Capacitive touch switches drop voltage and limits current

Tags: voltage, current, switches, capacitive

Bought two different touch switches/devices to toggle outputs to other devices. I use this on USB power so input is 5V. With use of a powerpack it can handle 2A max.

NOTICE: Ask my question here because none of them seems to specify output ratings.

- http://www.icstation.com/ttp223-touch-module-capacitive-settable-self-lockno-lock-switch-p-7561.html
- http://nl.aliexpress.com/item/XD-34-TTP224-4-Way-Capacitive-Touch-Switch-Digital-Sensor-Module-Board/32254066053.html

Test both and works fine except channel output is reduced, 1 volt. Doesn't seem to work as regular switch? I use this to switch an amplifier, sound card and bluetooth module but none of them seems to work because of limited current (and the voltage drop). Amplifier for example can operate between 3.3 and 6 volts but can't operate (weird click sounds and ttp223 led starts to flicker).

I don't think I do something wrong because it's a simple connection, +channel, -ground. The modules works perfectly without the touch switch.

Why do voltage drop? Any ideas? Is there a touch module available that doesn't reduce voltage and current? Like a regular switch?

Ask my question here because none of them seems to specify output ratings.

Comment: Why downvote? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ad for the icstation switch indicates that it has TTL logic level outputs - it is not a replacement for a mechanical switch, but can be used as an input device for a microcontroller or other logic circuit.  I expect the Aliexpress unit is similar, although I don't think the web site specifies the output characteristics (but I don't read that language).

What does the documentation for these two devices say about their output characteristics?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Okay, this is not a regular switch. Next question is, does it exist anyway? The documentation about the first one (single touhpad): http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/datasheet/TTP223_SPEC.pdf Doesn't say anything about output ratings only at operating or are the operating ratings the same as the output ratings? Very confusing.

Comment: The problem with most of the things from china is documentation. Most of the time it is confusing. Found the icstation ad when writing this answer, the one I bought from aliexpress has no description, also doesn't mention the board (chip) options like in the icsstation ad.

Comment: The TTP223 datasheet clearly states that the output can source 4 mA when High, and sink 8 mA when Low.  The TTP224 (AliExpress unit) datasheet doesn't list any electrical characteristics, but does say it has CMOS outputs, so I expect its outputs are similar to the TTP223.

Comment: Ah thanks, just edited my reply. Are there boards that can operate as regular switch or are they all digital?

Comment: Found some other touch switches but it's for (led) lights only (with dim features) or 12V. Can you point me into the right direction?

Comment: You could use either of these board to operate relays - the relay contacts would then act as "real" switches.

Comment: Relays, understand but no, it has to be simple and small as is possible with low power consumption. A switch as a switch.